# Sending GET request and getting status code + web content using php

Tags: php

How to send this (GET) request with all headers to a host, using php? and get status code and web content.

```
GET /Listen.xml HTTP/1.1
Host: ahost.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: close
Cookie: ClientId=1ED54D284B694B5885870D6CE02FC98C;
OIDC=1 Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Authorization: Basic YWFhOnNzcw==
```

Comment: You could use Guzzle http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/ or Curl https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php

If you update your question with examples of what you have tried I can help more

Comment: I suggest you check out guzzlehttp: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/ It's a php-library making HTTP-Requests really easy. You can conveniently install it with composer.

Comment: i want to send basic authentication and check is status 200 ( pass correct ) and 401 (not correct) - i need to add this headers that added before

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.example.com';

print_r(get_headers($url));

print_r(get_headers($url, 1));
?>
```

source: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php